# Do the Properties of Real Matrices apply to Complex Matrices or to matrices with entries from other fields, such as the Modulo 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Do basic properties that apply to Real Matrices , such as:

- **Determinant Properties**

det (AB ) = det(A) det(B)
det (A^T) = det(A), where T means the transpose
det (A^-1) = 1/det(A)
det (a A) = a^n det (A), where n = dimension of matrix

- **Matrix Multiplication Properties**

  A(B+C) = AB + AC

  (A+B)C = AC + BC

  A(BC) = (AB)C

  (AaB) = a (AB) , where a is a scalar

  AI = IA = A, where I = identity matrix

  AO = O
- **Matrix Inverse Properties**

  (a A) ^-1  = 1/a A^-1, where a is a scalar

  (AB)^-1 = B^-1 A^-1

  (A^T)^-1 = (A^-1)^T , where T means the transpose
- **Matrix Transpose Properties**

  (A^T)^T =A

  (A+B)^T = A^T + B^T

  (aA)^T = a(A^T)

  (AB)^T = B^T A^T
- Elementary Matrices and row operations

apply to Complex Matrices and Matrices from other fields?

Comment: It depends on exactly what properties you have in mind, but the basic stuff that doesn't involve inner products and so forth works over any field.

Comment: I added some of the properties I had in mind above ^

Comment: Yes, all of that stuff works over any field, and even over any commutative ring.

Comment: Thank you! I also wanted to ask, do you use the same techniques, and formulas, such as co-factor expansion to calculate the determinants of matrices with entries from the complex field or from other non-real fields.

Comment: Yes, all of that stuff works over any commutative ring as well.